# Three body problem - Half Life

Tags: quantum-mechanics, chaos-theory, three-body-problem

I did google this up but found nothing! I can't be the first to ask (the vague question)

"What is the half life of a gravitating three-body system?"

CLASSICALLY this means: Say I have three classical point particles of the same mass $M$ and start the system with some random initial conditions (pick whatever "good" distribution) that you choose. I expect that after some time the system decays into a single particle and a two-body problem. I draw the histogram of the "life times". (I haven't done this yet; I just came up with the problem). Do I get an exponential distribution? If so, what is the half-life? How does it depend on the initial conditions?
Hint: Almost all systems will decay eventually since the bounded states need specific measure zero initial conditions. In fancy words there is no full support (or at least 4 dimensional) preserved probability measure in the phase space. Any probability distribution will "evaporate" away. How fast does this happen?

QUANTUM MECHANICALLY this means: Consider the three-body problem with the Newtonian potential ($\hbar=G=M=1$). Are there any bounded states? (I guess not, but I can't prove it right now) If not how fast do the semi-bounded states decay? I don't know why the quantum mechanical problem matters. Maybe it could be used for heavy Baryonic half life calculations. I don't know I'm not an standard model expert.

Comment: Sadly, any experiment you try will be sabotaged by local  sophons.

Comment: Ok, seriously - the chaotic nature of  the generalized 3BP means half-life can't be calculated.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That is definitely not true. A half-life is a statistical quantity it is well defined even for a chaotic problem.

Comment: "I expect that after some time the system decays into a single particle and a two-body problem" - by which mechanism - tidal dissipation, gravitational waves emission, collisions..?

Comment: "the bounded states need specific measure zero initial conditions", do you have a source for this statement?

Comment: I suspect that, in the quantum case, bound states do exist. Helium atoms exist and I would be surprised if making all the interactions attractive destroyed them. (Although all the particles having the same mass could I suppose)

Comment: @K.Sadri  Yes you can always calculate a half-life.   But if you expect the higher moments of that calculation to be of a useable (i.e. small) magnitude, you'll be disappointed.   For any given starting position region in parameter space, the actual lifetime will be many powers (positive or negative) of the calculated halflife